# async in override context

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await

I am working on an iOS Xamarin Project. I need to create a share extension.

In a share extension, we can override this method:

```
    public override SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem[] GetConfigurationItems()
```

I want to call async methods in this method.
So i need to put an async keyword like this:

```
   public override async Task<SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem[]> GetConfigurationItems()
```

But C# compiler gives me an error, because override initial method has not this signature. So i do not know how to do...

Thanks

** EDIT **

Here is full example

```
        public override SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem[] GetConfigurationItems()
        {
            // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.


            var result = await service.make_computation());
            ....
         }
```

Comment: The compiler is correct. You can't do that. You going to have to provide more details about what it is you are actually trying to achieve so that help can be provided if able. Show how you want to make the async calls in a [mcve]

Comment: see my edit for the example

Comment: You may probably need to convert the service call to be synchronous.

Comment: Create an async wrapper in your subclass

Comment: What do you mean by "async wrapper"?